# Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, file, variables, undefined, fwrite

I am working on a facebook app and I am trying to write in a file that was opened in another php, but doesn't seem to work. My code looks like this:

**myphp.php**

```
include 'utils.php';
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');
require_once("AppInfo.php");
$likes=NULL;
global $fileout,$myfile;  //If I don't request the global ones, I got undefined variable
    if($user_id) {
          try {
            if(is_null($likes))
            $likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes'), 'data', array());
            if ($likes) {
                $arrayForJSON['likes']=$likes;
                 fwrite($fileout,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
            } 
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e){
             echo error_log($e);
        }
        echo "done";
        var_dump($arrayForJSON);
    }
    else
        echo "User not logged in";
```

Any idea why does this happen and how should I deal with it?

---

Complete **utils.php**

```
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');
require_once("AppInfo.php");
/**
 * @return the value at $index in $array or $default if $index is not set.
 */
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}

function he($str) {
  return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
'sharedSession' => true,
'trustForwarded' => true,
'file_upload' =>true
));
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$app_info = $facebook->api('/'. AppInfo::appID());
$app_name = idx($app_info, 'name', '');
if($user_id)
{
  $logoutUrl =$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
  else
  {
      $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
  }
if ($user_id) {
try {
  $permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
  // cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
  if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
    header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();
  }
}
  }
  $myfile="testson.json";
  $fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't open JSON file for writing");
$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
$arrayForJSON = array();
function getUpdatedTime()
{
    global $facebook,$user_id,$arrayForJSON;
    if($user_id) {
          try {

    $updated_time= idx($facebook->api('me/updated_time'), 'data', array());
    if($updated_time) {
        $arrayForJSON['updated_time']=$updated_time;
    } 
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e){
             error_log($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `utils.php` is in same directory as if in `myphp.php` is ?

Comment: If you have to use `global` then what code is in what functions

Comment: there's something going wrong in your includes. As a test, can you please put the two mentioned lines from utils.php behind the $likes = NULL line.

Comment: @Rikesh yes, it is. `user_id` is defined in `utils.php`. And it does its job

Comment: @jamie0726 works if I do that

Comment: @MarkBaker it isn't in any function, and that already seems weird that  I need to use `global`

Comment: can you add something like fwrite($fileout,"test"); die("X"); after the $likes line and remove the other two includes (Facebook sdk and AppInfo.php) as a next test? The fopen part is back in utils in this test. :-)

Comment: @jamie0726 if I remove the facebook sdk, then ` $likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes'), 'data', array()); ` will give an error

Comment: yes, I know. that's why I put the die() in the code to add. I want to find out if the problem is in one of the other includes or in utils. E.g. it might be that one of the other scripts closes fileout for some reason.

Comment: @jamie0726 same undefined variable errors. Plus an 'X'

Comment: Great, so the problem is in utils.php. Can you share the complete content of utils.php with us?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29233/discussion-between-jamie0726-and-bujanca-mihai)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell which particular *typo-like* mistake causes this error, but the code apparently have to be

**utils.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$myfile="testson.json";
//other variables
```

**myphp.php**

```
require 'utils.php';
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');
require_once("AppInfo.php");
if($user_id) {
    $likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes'), 'data', array());
    if ($likes) {
        $arrayForJSON['likes']=$likes;
        file_put_contents($myfile,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
        var_dump($arrayForJSON);
    } else {
        echo "Wrong user id";
    }
}
else
    echo "User not logged in";
```